# Receive OnClick event in activity from button inside custom TableRow

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I'm using different TableLayouts in my activity with custom TableRows.
When setting up the TableLayout I'm adding a OnClick Listener for the Button and one for the whole TableRow:

```
tr.getButton().setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d(null, "BTN CLICK");
   }    
});
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      Log.d(null, "TR CLICK");
   }
});
```

The problem is, that the listener for the TableRow is firing but not the one for the button.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Ok some more details...

The TableRow constructor:

```
public ItemTableRow(Context context, final Item item) {
        super(context);
        this.item = item;

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);

        buttonRemoveItem = new ImageButton(context);
        buttonRemoveItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.remove);

        buttonRemoveItem.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(buttonRemoveItem);

        TextView nameTextView = new TextView(context);
        nameTextView.setText(item.getName());
        nameTextView.setTextSize((float) 22.0);

        nameTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(nameTextView);
    }
```

The getter:

```
public ImageButton getButtonRemoveItem() {
    return buttonRemoveItem;
}
```

and the relevant part within the activity where the TableLayout is filled with content:

```
final ItemTableRow tr = new ItemTableRow(MeetingViewActivity.this, getMeeting().getSections().get(i));
                tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tr.getButtonRemoveItem().setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("service", "BTN CLICK");

                    }
                });

                tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MeetingViewActivity.this, SectionViewActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putSerializable("item", tr.getItem());
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }
                });

                tr.setPadding(40, 10, 0, 10);
                tableSections.addView(tr);
            }
```

Comment: what the tr.getButton() returns???

Comment: The tr constructor assigns button = new ImageButton(context); and the getter for the button just returns the button reference public ImageButton getButton() {
        return button;
    }